# Perl split regex non greedy fit with ">" as a separator

Tags: regex, perl, split, non-greedy

i'd like to split string with two or more ">", split function should brake string in first ">" and others put to second sting in list.

i try

```
$text = "tobash> hubba -> http://nonexists100101.net";

@op = split(/>{1}/, $text);
```

but split still breaks in every ">"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how `{1}` works (in fact, `{1}` never does anything at all). According to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) `split` has a third `limit` parameter. Try:

```
split(/>/, $text, 2)
```

That will return at most 2 substrings.